# FoxPro 9.0 LEFT JOIN is overwriting

Tags: foxpro

I am summarizing the result from a do while loop by using left join, but for some unknown reason its not joining any tables, just overwriting. What is it that I don't see?

```
DO WHILE counter < NbContracts
    SELECT depot_nr as depot_nr;
    WHERE rownum = counter FROM test3
    test33(depot_nr, counter)
    counter = counter + 1
ENDDO
CLOSE TABLES 

PROCEDURE test33(depot_nr_in, NbofTimes)
USE bs_case alias bs
SELECT  jaar    as jaar,;   
        Psres4pcgb  as &depot_nr_in;        
    WHERE Depot_nr = depot_nr_in FROM bs 
    COPY TO toJoin.dbf

DO CASE 
    CASE NbofTimes = 1
        SELECT * FROM toJoin.dbf 
        COPY TO joining.dbf
    CASE NbofTimes = NbContracts
        SELECT * FROM bsP.tmp as one LEFT JOIN joining.dbf as aggregated;
        ON (one.depot_nr = aggregated.depot_nr) into table final.dbf
        CLOSE TABLES
        ENDPROC
    OTHERWISE
        SELECT &depot_nr_in FROM toJoin.dbf as a LEFT JOIN joining.dbf as b;
            ON a.jaar = b.jaar INTO TABLE final.dbf
        CLOSE TABLES
        USE final.dbf 
        COPY TO joining.dbf
ENDCASE

CLOSE TABLES
CLOSE DATABASES
ENDPROC
```

The issues appears in the OTHERWISE section (I think) and for another unknown reason my FoxPro is not recogninzing the CASE structure (bonus question, but less off a priority).

A small illustration on what I want

```
test3.dbf
===================================
22
31
32
23
```

NbofTimes = 1

```
final.dbf
===================================
year     22
-----------------------------------
  1     val1
  2     val2
  3     val3
 ...    ...
  80    val80
```

NbofTimes = 2

```
final.dbf
===================================
year      22      31
-----------------------------------
  1      val1    val4
  2      val2    val5
  3      val3    val6
 ...     ...     ...
 80      val80   val81
```

NbofTimes = 3

```
final.dbf
===================================
 year    22      31        32
-----------------------------------
  1     val1    val4      val7
  2     val2    val5      val8
  3     val3    val6      val9
 ...     ...       ...    ...
  80     val80   val81     val82
```

NbofTimes = 4

```
final.dbf
===================================
year    22      31        32       23
-----------------------------------
  1    val1    val4      val7     val10
  2    val2    val5      val8     val11
  3    val3    val6      val9     val12
 ...    ...    ...       ...      ...
  80   val80   val81     val82    val83
```

What is happening now is that my final table is never growing it just contains the last iteration. help.....

Answer (score 0):

I see this is your 4th iteration of this same question, trying to get an answer.  What is going on is really poorly structured and sampled out.  You are showing arbitrary values 1, 2, 3 ... 80, 4, 5, 6... 81, etc.  Your data all appears to originate from BS_Case table.  It appears you are trying to create some sort of cross-tab comparison per each Depot.

Now, there may be 200 entries in your BS_Case table consisting of (for example), 5 unique Depots.  Depot "A" could have 40 entries, Depot "B" could have 10, Depot "C" has 18 and remainder split between Depot "D" and "E".

OR -- does EVERY DEPOT have the same number of entries in the BS_Case table... Such as a business like McDonalds that has hundreds of stores and all report daily sales to the same central point on a daily basis, that all stores have the same # of records.

If so, it looks like you are trying to show comparisons BETWEEN each of the Depots.

So, example is raw data records would be something like...

```
BS_CASE
Record #  Depot_NR  Psres4pcgb
1         DepotA    AValue1
2         DepotB    BValue1
3         DepotC    CValue1
4         DepotA    AValue2 test
5         DepotB    BValue2 another
6         DepotC    CValue2 confirm
```

Your list of DISTINCT Depots represented per your outer loop would result in

```
JustDepotList
Record #  Depot_NR
1         DepotA
2         DepotB
3         DepotC
```

And what you are hoping to get is something like

```
Final
Record  DepotA        DepotB            DepotC
1       AValue1       BValue1           CValue1
2       AValue2 test  BValue2 another   CValue2 confirm
```

So, please confirm some accuracy to what I'm presenting here.

ALSO, EDIT THIS QUESTION (not my answer, but this version of your question) WITH REVISIONS instead of re-posting yet another for the same original question.  In your edit, post, show some ACTUAL Data and how close am I to what you want.

I dont see any true "aggregations" such as min(), max(), sum() values, but aggregation ONLY to the respect of add another column corresponding to each depot.  I'm sure I and others could better help you with better clarification of what you ultimately want.

Comment: Hi, yes my aggregation is in the respect of adding columns and not column values such as min(), max(), sum() etc. I was able to solve the otherwise snippet of code, and are now struggling to understand why my do case is not working.  Sorry if my explanation was not clear enough, I have spend to many hours on this and don't see what is obvious and not.

Comment: @orongo, can you edit this posting and show ALL the code.  You have some partials left out and not quite getting your start / variable for total number of cycles to process.  Also, some samples of the "jaar" values and such, I might be better able a new solution and simplify HOW to get what you are looking for.

Comment: @Orongo, to see the actual depot, jaar, Psres4pcgb values in natural display (browse) of the data would really help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my query by using this snippet of code under the OTHERWISE statement. It's a bit of an hack, but it's working =)

```
    SELECT * FROM toJoin.dbf LEFT JOIN joining.dbf;
        ON toJoin.jaar = joining.jaar INTO TABLE finaltmp.tmp
    CLOSE TABLES
    USE finaltmp.tmp
    ALTER TABLE finaltmp.tmp;
        DROP COLUMN jaar_a;
        RENAME COLUMN jaar_b TO jaar
    COPY TO final.dbf
    USE final.dbf 
    COPY TO joining.dbf
```